# How to copy a file from windows7 to Virtual Machine ubuntu

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware

I have installed Virtual Machine in my windows and inside VM, added Ubuntu.
So I need to copy a file from my windows machine to VM Ubuntu.
How can i do it?

Answer (score 2):

If you have sshd enables on your Ubuntu guest and host and guest are able to communicate via LAN with each other, you could use the scp to copy files. On your windows host you can use WinSCP.

Comment: SSH is not enabled, how can we enable ssh in my VM ubuntu.
I am able to see /etc/ssh/ssh_config file.
What step I need to follow to enable ssh.

Comment: ssh localhost
ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused

Answer (score 2):

There are many methods to do it: (i recommend Method 3)

---

**Method 1:**
Mount a shared folder that's on the Windows host onto Ubuntu. That way you don't even need to copy them.

Go to Virtual Machine » Virtual Machine Settings » Shared Folders.

---

**Method 2**
The easiest way to do is to install the VMware Tools in Ubuntu, then you are able to drag the file into the Ubuntu VM.

To install VMware Tools, you need to switch to Ubuntu, then go to the VMware menu VM » Install VMware Tools, and then follow the instructions to finish the installation.

---

**Method 3**
Login to your linux machine (ubuntu) in vmware.
Click on "Places" and go to "Network" .
Go inside "Windows Network" and go deeper and you will find "user" and then "Public" .
This folder is nothing but your windows "Public" folder.

You can use this folder as a shared folder between host and guest machine.

**Refer: [For detailed description](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97031/how-to-transfer-files-from-windows-to-ubuntu-instaled-on-vmware)**

Comment: Thank you !!
Method 2 works for me,
Now I am able to copy a file via drag&drop.

Comment: Method1 I tried.
I have created a folder and added in 
device-->sharedfolder settings-->sharedfolders==>MachineFolders as a key-value, but how can we copy a file via terminal by using cp command.

Comment: you first check the shared folder is available in terminal or not using cd 'location of shared folder'  command.